# Eclipse - Install new Software not appearing in the Help menu

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use Eclipse with Android. After installing CDT tools I lost the "**Install new Software**" option from the help menu.

It is quite frustrating, it simply stopped showing up. Instead, I have this now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdrL.png

I am not sure what to do and how to recover it. No error appeared, just restarting (after actually installing software using the item)

Comment: Looks like you've lost the feature and plugins that contribute the software update functionality. I've never heard of that. What, exactly, did you install most recently?

Comment: The last thing I installed (with the "Install New Software" item) was the CDT tools. I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2onPuDZQVY. (At 3:00)

Comment: That's odd, CDT by itself should not cause the software update feature to fail or disappear. I'm curious, you state you want to use Eclipse for Android development; why are you installing CDT in that case?

Comment: I am trying to install openCV as well, and apparently it is one of the requirements (it will not compile otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Window > Customize Perspective' and click on the 'Menu Visibility' tab.

Expand the 'Help' section and you should be able to check the missing options there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks greg, but craziness persists. I do not have the same option as you do in Menu Visibility. I tried it and... http://i.imgur.com/g5UsCMd.png

Comment: Hi,
I have the same problem. however there is no "Install New Software" choice in menu visibility too. 
you should noticed that I installed eclipse process framework composer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rolling back the last installation to return your Eclipse to a good state. In the **About Eclipse** dialog, click **Installation Details** and then go to the **Installation History** tab. There you can select a previous configuration and revert to it.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. However, I will try to install everything from scratch with a better understanding of what each new module does.